# How to remove google search bar of home screen from android source code of AOSP

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, operating-system, android-source

I have installed android open source project [AOSP 10] on my system and buid it and have run the emulator. It is showing the default google search bar on the top of the home screen. I want to remove that google search bar from there to make the home screen clear.
For removing that I have modified one file but I am not sure about which file I have to modified to remove that section.

I have modified an AndroidManifest.xml file which is at the directory "Android_AOSP/packages/apps/QuickSearchBox/AndroidManifest.xml", but that file have removed only the search icon but the background layout is still showing there.
Before the editing the following code the above search layout was same as the below google search layout.

I have just commented one section of the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.android.quicksearchbox" >

    <original-package android:name="com.android.quicksearchbox" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />

    <!-- Permissions needed by the default corpora. We request these instead of just relying on
         GLOBAL_SEARCH so that we can use the default corpora when not in the system
         partition. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>

    <!-- Permissions used by GoogleSearch. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@mipmap/search_app_icon"
                 android:name=".QsbApplicationWrapper"
                 android:theme="@style/Theme.QuickSearchBox"
                 android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
<!--
        <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask"
                  android:theme="@style/Theme.QuickSearchBox.Search">
 -->                 
            <!-- Show app icon in Launcher. -->
<!--
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
-->            <!-- Handle global search. -->
<!--            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.search.action.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.search.action.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="com.android.launcher.toolbar_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_google_logo_normal" />
        </activity>

-->
        <receiver android:name=".SearchWidgetProvider"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/search_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".google.GoogleSearch"
                android:label="@string/google_search_label"
                android:icon="@mipmap/google_icon"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/google_searchable" />
        </activity>

        <provider android:name=".google.GoogleSuggestionProvider"
            android:label="@string/google_search_label"
            android:authorities="com.android.quicksearchbox.google"
            android:exported="true" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have changed the selected code only showing in the given image file.
And the changes happened after the build again which are showing in the emulator.
I want to fully remove the above search layout from the home screen but it is not happening.
Before editing the code it were looking same like the below search layout.
I have also tried by commenting all the code written inside the manifest tag section. But it not doing any changes except the showing changes. And if I delete this file then it will start giving the error.
I have tried by deleting the full 'QuickSearchBox' folder but after doing that no any changes happening in that section.

[image: Check the code and layout changes in the given image. I only have commented the selected code and it showing changes in the emulator]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I used to remove the default home screen google search box was wrong.

I have find the main solution of removing it without making much changes in the code.
Follow the following steps to remove it.

Step 1 :    Go to the following directory inside your **AOSP** source directory

Path  :  ***packages/apps/Launcher3/src/com/android/launcher3/config/***

Step 2 :    Open the file named  " BaseFlags.java "

Step 3 :    Find the following line of code and make change as following from " true "   to   " false "

```
// Enable moving the QSB on the 0th screen of the workspace

public static final boolean QSB_ON_FIRST_SCREEN = false;    // For show 'home screen search bar' make it true. // By default it was true
```

Step 4 :    Save the file.

Step 5 :    Make the source code and check the result. Google search bar get removed.

Comment: On AOSP 12, the file is FeatureFlags.java (in the same folder)

Comment: Thanks for more information about updated version of AOSP. I was found that in AOSP 10

Answer (score 0):

thats not part of Android system, its Launcher app and design. I can't find a dedicated doc page, but found some tutorial [how to make own Launcher app](https://www.androidauthority.com/make-a-custom-android-launcher-837342-837342/). you can write own or find some 3rd-party with opened source and "friendly" licence, and modify it by removing this bar (if even present), then you may replace default launcher app in system files

what you have done: you just modified app responsible for handling this widget actions, still in fact yet another app (launcher) is implementing this widget for own "desktop" design

Comment: I am a beginner,
I am trying to build my custom rom by modifying AOSP,
I have installed android open source project (AOSP) version 10, and I am trying to customise it according to my choice. But I am unable to remove that google search bar which occur on the top of the home screen. And it is not movable( I can not do drag and drop it) to remove also. It is fixed at that place on the screen. That is not like other widget which can be added or removed on the screen.
I just want to edit that default launcher of this AOSP to make my custom rom.

Comment: I have installed AOSP by using this following command
`python ~/.bin/repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-10.0.0_r41`
After building the AOSP I get [These files](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-10.0.0_r41) on my system and I am doing modifications in that.

Comment: I've found in these sources [`Launcher3`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Launcher3/) app, which is probably a default launcher. it have only one `Activity` in manifest called [`Launcher`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Launcher3/src/com/android/launcher3/Launcher.java), inspect it

Comment: I do not know about which section of the launcher is responsible for that home screen section to edit to remove from the default home screen.
I think that layout is showing from any .xml file. But I am unable to find which file containing that section.
If you have time then can connect with me through [whatsapp](https://wa.me/917985532371) or email : anurag.cse016@gmail.com

Comment: sadly I'm not planning to investigate and modify this app, too much time. now its your job, I've just pointed you the way. also way easier would be to replace this app with some other "simpler" launcher (open source or downloaded on another device from Play Store and exported do APK). note that somewhere in srouces there is a "default pointer" pointing on default launcher, or maybe system just use one and only app of this kind? worth check, good luck

Comment: Thanks for your this much help, But I just want to do modified not to change whole launcher.